# WSS4j - WS client Interceptor : Missing Digital Signature

Tags: digital-signature, wss, wss4j

Trying to implement WSS for a Webservice client with keystore entries for PrivateKey and TrustedCert for Server.
The interceptor code for the outgoing request is as shown below.

```
// Outgoing
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    interceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature Encrypt");

    //Signature
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureUser("privatekey");
    interceptor.setSecurementPassword("XXXXXXXX");
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(truststoreCrypto.getObject());
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts(
            "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;" +
                    "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"
    );
    interceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    //interceptor.setSecurementSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1");
    //interceptor.setSecurementSignatureDigestAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1");

    // Encryption
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionUser("privatekey");
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(keystoreCrypto.getObject());
    interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");

 interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionSymAlgorithm(
               "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc");

  interceptor.setSecurementEncryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm(
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5");
    interceptor.
            setSecurementEncryptionParts("{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature;" + "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");
```

The final soap request created does not have any ds:Signature tag. Any idea why ?
Expecting the following -

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                    wsu:Id="X509-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300734">
                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
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300838" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="root soapenv"
                                                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300787">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="root"
                                                        xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>THnDnGbR93ALSgnd9QVpHbpqffo=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    DLWONZZiqWwgmPte9UKWesqKNdmxClIY+lQcxnaNo0RaxOb6DzhGZM5dY4rmLFm6ohQ4O1R/j/3431ZUKFAPLTdTil74BX3LXREB5drtz+ki9v0v3GOszBNjEWG3pUAw0J3R5vajZs69sq8mtmDH1t1JQMjiVdiJXh2TlGA0QxGWO3EWadC3gkAfcT71LDeNopVvkiqtEehWRSbx29fmbyyukyMsiIjeGJn/a6aFTLmo2UnxZ8u28KfytCeGYMeT+ntJRTxDL6TuhCLvnAUZCcv+3GNaDSywLQjrwJHV/0jrJCgeeHAiq+zRvjPjlQE9IDdJbsVNsbMwXon8Iit/Sw==
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300765">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300766">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300734"
                                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                    wsu:Id="357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300402">
                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
            </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300381" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300402"
                                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>
                        HTeWqiTy9Iu19kHBCqjNip9ZIXZe5SxOHHlcRgLaafVY1EpgiVjz1va4LrGEywo+Kz7xb68dMKz6tp+uW2shCtD4IJeivq5LgpujrdTzl77Ih/LPV1HbQs43VfR0jINXGuFZ9XU5gxIJVWSR5s6KEjtasqZyvUu1lSJzkysMoPpD8f+eJcJeDfveZrwCev8OmG4IFSnwy+n1zPtCgwJSECMFLYGX6LnAAw5knYvs9wseOmrTxh5G/KDbxGy+TUGcQD89MBR0RkzGG47xZ2+0gKQxRVnwqbzScV1pMFKS+yg8YPMFJJJkCcwO+L5YDOjWEYOKpECBNrgP6eEY2eTdvw==
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                    <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-357F972C3B28B16BEC15325300300543"/>
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </wsse:Security>
```

However it is missing the ds:Signature tag entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the base from Spring interceptors to Apache CXF + WSS4j.
I was able to add properties that are not supported via Spring classes.